# How can I read a file line by line and redirect each line to a variable in shell scripting?

Tags: linux, shell

I am using ksh shell.
I want to use those variables and get the values when I call (p1,p2,p3,p4). The file test1.log may contain any number of lines hence cannot define it as p1...p4. The script itself should consider the number of lines and assign variables accordingly in sequence.

Please help on this. Below is my input file test1.log

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
```

I want my output as

```
p1=ABC
p2=DEF
p3=GHI
p4=JKL
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: Can be done but why not use an array?

Comment: cat $file |while read LINE
> do
> for out in $LINE
> do
> echo "part $((i++))= $out"
> done
> done
ksh[5]: i++: more tokens expected

Answer (score 1):

You may leverage the `-n` option of `cat` which plots the line numbers. With some Perl substitution afterwards, a simple solution would be :

```
$ cat -n test1.log | perl -pe 's/^(\s*)(\d+)(\s*)/p$2=/'
p1=ABC
p2=DEF
p3=GHI
p4=JKL
```

If you want to access those variables within a script, I suggest you use the `eval` command the following way :

```
while read line; do
  eval "$line" ;
done < <(cat -n tmp | perl -pe 's/^(\s*)(\d+)(\s*)/p$2="/; s/$/"/')

echo p1 : $p1
echo p2 : $p2
```

Note that in this second example, I added the support for lines where you have spaces inside by adding double quotes around. I use the following input file :

```
$ cat test1.log
ABC foo
DEF
GHI
JKL
```

Directly from the command line, you can of course run the `while` part and get p1,p2,... available in the shell.

If you want to "load" the variables separately and access them inside other scripts, you may use the `export` command (I prefer to add it in the Perl substitution part) :

```
while read line; do eval "$line" ; done < <(cat -n tmp | perl -pe 's/^(\s*)(\d+)(\s*)/export p$2="/; s/$/"/')
```

After running this command in the shell, a simple script like

```
$ cat tmp.sh
echo p1 : $p1
echo p2 : $p2
echo p3 : $p3
echo p4 : $p4
```

will then output

```
$ ./tmp.sh
p1 : ABC foo
p2 : DEF
p3 : GHI
p4 : JKL
```

Enjoy

Comment: Thank you.. got the output but those values should be exported into variables i.e., when i call p1 anywhere else in the script, it should take the value ABC.  $ cat -n test1_new.log| perl -pe 's/^(\s*)(\d+)(\s*)/p$2=/'
p1=ABC
p2=DEF
p3=GHI
p4=JKL

Comment: If you want to access those variables, you may use the `eval` command. I modified my answer accordingly

Comment: You're welcome ! Please note the answer as accepted ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
vars=`cat data.txt`

inc=0
for v in ${vars}
do
        inc=`expr $inc + 1`
        declare "param$inc=$v";
        localParam="param$inc"
        echo "${localParam}=${!localParam}";
done
```

Comment: $ for v in ${vars}
> done
> inc=`expr $inc + 1`
> declare "param$inc=$v";
> localParam="param$inc"
> echo "${localParam}=${!localParam}";
> done
/usr/bin/ksh[4]: declare:  not found
/usr/bin/ksh[6]: "${localParam}=${!localParam}": bad substitution

Comment: I am getting above error.. unable to get desired output.

Answer (score 0):

In ksh, you can use `eval` like this

```
cat $file |
  while read LINE 
  do  
    for out in $LINE  
    do  
      eval part$((++i))="$out" 
    done 
  done
echo "p1=$part1"
echo "p2=$part2"
echo "p1=$part3"
echo "p4=$part4"
```

I have also changed `i++` to `++i` so that indexing starts at 1 rather than 0.

Answer (score 0):

If your input data indeed don't contain any white space characters, you can do it with

```
grep -v '^$' YOURFILE | nl -s= -w99 | tr -s ' ' p
```

Comment: Thank you.. I got the desired output but the value should be exported to variable.

Comment: cat -n test1_new.log| perl -pe 's/^(\s*)(\d+)(\s*)/p$2=/'
p1=ABC
p2=DEF
p3=GHI
p4=JKL

Comment: when I echo $p1 nothing is displayed.. after the above output I want to call p1 somewhere else in the script and that should take ABC as the value. Please help..

Comment: @Gooty : Well, it's up to you to use the output of the command I mentioned. For example, you could write it to a temporary file, source the file, and delete the temp file afterwards.